# Outlook Add In (Exchange)- Create/Forward email - JavaScript

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have a problem with creating a script that creates/forwards an email in outlook to a constant recipiant.

the plan was to select keywords from checkboxes in its form. by pressing an inplemented button, the add-in should forward the opened email with a new subject from the checked checkboxes.

since i am very new to webdesign and js i would like to know if the idea could be realized without further ado. i have already browsed several forums and found out that sending email requires a web server and email client, which is out of the question due to the dynamic use and data security. also

I have already created the form of the add in. since this has no functions yet, i save posting a code/progress.

Any feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for moving/forwarding items in Outlook. The web add-in is working under the currently selected item only. But you may consider using `EWS` or [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) for implementing the required functionality.